# Windows conditional variable is not signaled when expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am writing code for a memory buffer which allows threads to share memory with each other.  I am trying to use critical sections and condition variables for synchronization.

Here is my source code:

```
    size_t ReadBuffer(char *dst_buffer)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_CriticalSection);

    if (!m_bBufferReady)
    {
        printf("ReadBuffer: wait for ready buffer\n");   
        SleepConditionVariableCS (&BufferNotEmpty, &m_CriticalSection, INFINITE);
        printf("ReadBuffer: after wait for ready buffer\n"); 
    }
    if (m_uRealSize == 0)
    {

    }
    memcpy(dst_buffer, m_pBuffer, m_uRealSize);
    size = m_uRealSize;
    m_uRealSize = 0;
    m_bBufferReady = FALSE;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CriticalSection); 
    WakeConditionVariable (&BufferNotFull);
    if (size != 0)
    {
        SleepConditionVariableCS (&BufferNotEmpty, &m_CriticalSection, INFINITE);
    }

    return size;
}

size_t WriteBuffer(const char *src_buffer, size_t size)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_CriticalSection);
    if (m_bBufferReady)
    { 
        SleepConditionVariableCS (&BufferNotFull, &m_CriticalSection, INFINITE);
        printf("WriteBuffer: after wait for free buffer\n"); 
    }
    if (size > m_uBufferSize)
        size = m_uBufferSize;
    memcpy(m_pBuffer, src_buffer, size);
    m_uRealSize = size;
    m_bBufferReady = TRUE;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CriticalSection); 
    WakeConditionVariable (&BufferNotEmpty);
    SleepConditionVariableCS (&BufferNotFull, &m_CriticalSection, INFINITE);
    return size;
}
```

When WriteBuffer is called with a zero size buffer it is treated as the end of communication.  At that point the reading thread exits correctly but the writing thread hangs on the last call to `SleepConditionVariableCS`.

When I use Windows events instead of conditional variables, everything works OK, so I don't think this is a problem with the algorithm. But I want to be able to use conditional variables instead of events. Is there some restriction to the use of conditional variables?  Or maybe it is connected to the critical section somehow?

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: "In the end of it..." In the end of what? There is no code that exits the thread.

Comment: Why is `ReadBuffer()` sleeping on `BufferNotEmpty` at the end? The buffer has already been consumed, so just move on and process it. Let the next call to `ReadBuffer()` sleep if it needs to wait for data. Why is `WriteBuffer()` sleeping on `BufferNotFull` at the end. The buffer has already been written, so just move on. Let the next call to `WriteBuffer()` sleep if it needs to wait for consumption to free space. You are making the producer and consumer wait on each other too much. Also, I think you need to wake the variables while you are still inside the CS lock instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is that you're calling SleepConditionalVariableCS after exiting the critical section.

From the [documentation for SleepConditionVariableCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This critical section must be entered exactly once by the caller at the time SleepConditionVariableCS is called.

As described in the [documentation for LeaveCriticalSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169(v=vs.85).aspx), exiting a critical section you don't own causes an error that "may cause another thread using EnterCriticalSection to wait indefinitely".